# remove from the string number where more than 4 digits

Tags: r, regex

here the data

```
mydf=structure(list(X.U.FEFF.ID = c(3951L, 3955L, 3956L, 3957L, 3958L
), ITEM_SUM = c(29.9, 55.99, 59, 40.95, 47.25), QUANTITY = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PRICE = c(29.9, 55.99, 59, 40.95, 47.25), NDS10 = c(0, 
0, 5.36, 0, 4.3), NDS18 = c(0, 8.54, 0, 6.25, 0), id = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("*2108609 fsfhsfghsgfhjdfsdh", "2013077 a[osdig[aodifg[ad", 
"2030918 Пhsapsgiju[aeri 180г", "3420159 rgyaeghpiudarsfghpuashg 900г", 
"any text"), class = "factor"), ID_C_REGCODES_CASH_VOUCHER = c(3945L, 
3953L, 3953L, 3953L, 3953L), DISCOUNTNAME = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), DISCOUNTSUM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X.U.FEFF.ID", 
"ITEM_SUM", "QUANTITY", "PRICE", "NDS10", "NDS18", "id", "ID_C_REGCODES_CASH_VOUCHER", 
"DISCOUNTNAME", "DISCOUNTSUM"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

in the `id` column

```
any text
*2108609 fsfhsfghsgfhjdfsdh
3420159 rgyaeghpiudarsfghpuashg 900г
2030918 Пhsapsgiju[aeri 180г
2013077 a[osdig[aodifg[ad
```

from lines where in numbers more than 4 digits, i need  remove such numbers from the line.

Desired output, that id column would be

```
any text
fsfhsfghsgfhjdfsdh
rgyaeghpiudarsfghpuashg 900г
Пhsapsgiju[aeri 180г
a[osdig[aodifg[ad
```

How to do it?

Comment: You are also removing the asterisk in the second line. Why?

Comment: Try `trimws(gsub("^.*\\d{4,}", "", mydf$id))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, i forgot say *,$ are not needed symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another regex.

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]*\\d{4,}", "", mydf$id)
#[1] "any text"                      " fsfhsfghsgfhjdfsdh"          
#[3] " rgyaeghpiudarsfghpuashg 900г" " Пhsapsgiju[aeri 180г"        
#[5] " a[osdig[aodifg[ad"
```

If you also want to remove the white space before the result, wrap it with `trimws`:

```
trimws(gsub("[^[:alnum:]]*\\d{4,}", "", mydf$id))
```

**Edit.**

If you want to remove numbers with more than 4 digits in several columns, `lapply` a function along the lines of the `gsub` statement above.

`df` is a data.frame with two columns with such numbers, columns `1` and `2`.

```
df <- mydf["id"]
df$new <- mydf[["id"]]

df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(s) 
  trimws(gsub("[^[:alnum:]]*\\d{4,}", "", s)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`sub` is an option

```
sub("[^.]\\d{4,} ", "", mydf$id)
#[1] "any text"                    
#[2] "fsfhsfghsgfhjdfsdh"          
#[3] "rgyaeghpiudarsfghpuashg 900г"
#[4] "Пhsapsgiju[aeri 180г"        
#[5] "a[osdig[aodifg[ad"
```

To change the column in your data do

```
mydf$id <- sub("[^.]\\d{4,} ", "", mydf$id)
```

Comment: it works, but as output i have only one cleaned column(id), but this cleaned column must on data set mydf with another columns))

Comment: This doesn't work on "12345 a 123 b 12345 c 123 d 12345"

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Good catch. Any idea how to improve it (still need to learn a lot when it comes to regex). Best

Comment: I'm not a regex master either to be honest, and the awkward thing with this issue is the extra space. Using `trimws` as Rui did we can modify slightly your solution to take either a space in the end of the end of the string and then it works : `trimws(gsub("[^.]\\d{4,}( |$)", "\\1", "12345 a 123 b 12345 c 123 d 12345"))`